# What would the resulting karyotype be if someone with Klinefelter syndrome fertilized an "empty" egg?

Tags: human-genetics, chromosome, development, dna-replication, sex-chromosome

> [Endoreduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoreduplication): is a form of nuclear polyploidization that results in multiple, uniform copies of chromosomes. This process is common in plants and animals, especially in tissues with high metabolic activity, and it generally occurs in cells that are terminally differentiated.
>   <sup>[Investigating the hows and whys of DNA endoreduplication.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11283162) - Larkins, et. al.</sup>

What would be the karyotype of the sex chromosomes of a [complete hydatidiform mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_pregnancy) that was the result of a sperm (monospermy) of someone with [Klinefelter syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klinefelter_syndrome) (47,XXY) fertilizing an "empty" female egg?

I know that in a situation without Klinefelter syndrome the sperm inside the egg would double all it's chromosomes by endoreduplication (since the mother's chromosomes are all missing), but in this situation there would not be a need to double the sex chromosomes if the sperm already contains "XX" or "XY" (Since Klinefelter syndrome has 4 possibilities for a sperm : Y, X, XY, XX).

Or would it be that the cell doubles every chromosome if there are too many missing?

Comment: I added some links to your question for those that might be unfamiliar with molar pregnancy, etc - it's always a good idea to add links for clarity to help others understand your question